# log4j2.xml file has KeyValuePair set in MDC. If key is not set, how can we omit the value altogether from the log line?

Tags: java, log4j2, mdc

If I have a KeyValuePair in my JsonLayout appender, and that pair is not set in the MDC, is there a way to exclude the value from the logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java,

You can use ':-' for null value in log4j2.xml

Example:

```
<KeyValuePair key="traceId" value="$${ctx:traceId:-}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a routing appender with a js script.  The script grabs the variable into a variable and compares it to itself.  If the value is equal to its own replacer - it means it wasn't replaced.  In this case, I don't route to the appender that has that KeyValuePair - I route to another one that doesn't.